# Is a finite flat groupoid of affine schemes equivalent to an action groupoid of a finite flat group scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathscr X$ be an algebraic stack with a finite locally free presentation $\pi:X\to\mathscr X$ where $X$ is an affine scheme. Is it possible to find a presentation $\mathscr X=[Y/H]$ where $Y$ is an affine scheme over a base scheme $S$ and $H$ is a finite locally free group scheme over $S$ that acts on $Y$?
In other words, is the finite locally free groupoid of affine schemes
$[X\times_{\mathscr X}X\rightrightarrows X]$ equivalent to an action groupoid of the form
$[Y\times_SH\rightrightarrows Y]$?

I assume that the answer is no, so I am asking for an example.

Note: If $\pi$ has degree $n$, then one can write $\mathscr X=[Z/\operatorname{GL}_n]$ for an affine scheme $Z$; here $Z$ is the scheme that parametrizes trivializations of the locally free module $\pi_*\mathscr O_X$.

Comment: Let $S=\mathrm{Spec } \mathbb{C}$. Take $\mathcal{X}$ to be the weighted projective line $\mathcal{P}(1,2)$ defined as the stacky quotient of $\mathbb{A}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ by the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ given by $\lambda\cdot (x,y) =(\lambda x, \lambda^2 y)$. This stack $\mathcal{X}$ is not uniformisable, i.e., there is no variety (or algebraic space) $Y$ and finite group $G$ such that $\mathcal{X} \cong [Y/G]$. Equivalently, by Chapter 6 of Laumon-Moret-Bailly, there is no variety $U$ with a finite etale morphism $U\to \mathcal{X}$. To prove this, use Riemann-Hurwitz ...tbc

Comment: Now, this doesn't answer your question, because this stack does not have affine coarse space (note that the coarse space of your $\mathcal{X}$ is automatically affine, assuming its inertia stack is finite). You should be able to adapt this example to answer your question. (Note that, since $S=\mathrm{Spec } \mathbb{C}$, every finite locally free group scheme over $S$ is a constant group scheme associated to some finite group $G$.)

Comment: Actually, now I am wondering about my "You should be able to adapt this..." statement. In fact, if $X$ is a smooth finite type separated DM stack with affine coarse space, then it is probably obtained as an iterated root stack and canonical stack construction (see Geraschenko-Satriano's paper on bottom-up characterization of DM stacks). If it's just root stacks, then you do obtain a uniformisable stack. So, this just means that in the case of stacky curves with affine coarse space, the answer to your question is "yes".